# Reading a 32 bit hexadecimal into a long in 64 bit environment

Tags: c, hex, 32bit-64bit

I have written a long to file represented as a 32 bit hexadecimal. I have done this in a 32 bit environment.

Should I be able to read the hexdecimal value from a file in a 64 bit environment and convert it to a long using

```
 strtoul(hexString, NULL, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as `unsigned long` type is as least `32-bit` wide. If `unsigned long` is larger in your new environment, it is not an issue.